# import excel in datagrid view vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to import Excel in datagridview using this methods in the code below. But I have an error in this line "invalidOperationException" can't get the data to show up

```
cnnExcel.Open()
```

and here is the whole code

comboBox as cmbExcel
Having some if condition for supporting depend on excel version (2003 - 2013)

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim cnnExcel As New OleDbConnection
Public Function GetExccelSheetNames() As String()
    Dim ConStr As String = ""
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim opExcel As New OpenFileDialog
    opExcel.Filter = "(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|(*.xls)|*.xls"
    opExcel.ShowDialog()
    Dim pathExcel As String = opExcel.FileName
    If pathExcel.Trim = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Excel File !")
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Dim Ext As String = pathExcel.Substring(pathExcel.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
        If Ext.Length = 3 Then
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathExcel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
        ElseIf Ext.Length = 4 Then
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathExcel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES';"
        End If
        cnnExcel = New OleDbConnection(ConStr)
        cnnExcel.Open()
        dt = cnnExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
        If dt Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Dim excelSheetNames As [String]() = New [String](dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            excelSheetNames(i) = row("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
            i += 1
        Next
        cnnExcel.Close()
        Return excelSheetNames
    End If
End Function
```

Added a Button as btnBrows to brows excel file from any location in local drive

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    cmbsheet.DataSource = GetExccelSheetNames()
End Sub
Dim dt As New DataTable
```

Then Finally having a button to view the excel in datagridview

```
Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + cmbsheet.SelectedValue.ToString() + "]", cnnExcel)
    cnnExcel.Open()
    dt.Clear()
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
    cnnExcel.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a reference. It's 100% working. I'm using this in one of my applications. Put this code on your import button.

```
Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Me.TextBox1.Text = path.ToString

    Try
        Me.dgvFile.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataTable
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        Me.dgvFile.DataSource = DtSet

        MyConnection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("File successfully imported")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already found the solution. The code was alright I only need to install  AccessDatabaseEngine.exe

Comment: Oh ok. Glad to here. Goodluck :)